# Switch character to play animation() in Unity3D using c#

Tags: c#, 2d, unity, animation, character

I have two or more 2D character (Character A, B, n..). 
I made an animation on the character using the Animator class "AnimCharacter.cs". 
if i press the 'PgUp' character 'A' can call the function AnimCharacter.cs, when i press 'PgUp' again, character 'B' can call that function so the character A is in idle.
I've tried to make the class "aktifChar" but still error. Everybody can help me ? Thanks

**"AnimCharacter.cs"**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AnimCharacter : MonoBehaviour {
    public float maxSpeed = 10f;
    bool facingRight = true;
    Animator anim;
    bool grounded = false;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    float groundRadius = 0.2f;
    public LayerMask whatisGround;
    public float jumpForce = 700f;
    bool doubleJump = false;

    void Start () {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        try{
            grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (groundCheck.position, groundRadius, whatisGround);
            anim.SetBool ("Ground", grounded);

            if (grounded)
                doubleJump = false;

            anim.SetFloat ("vSpeed", rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

            //if(!grounded) return;

            float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
            anim.SetFloat ("Speed", Mathf.Abs(move));
            rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
            if (move > 0 && !facingRight)
                Flip ();
            else if (move < 0 && facingRight)
                Flip ();
        }catch{

        }
    }

    void Update(){
        if ((grounded || !doubleJump) && Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
            anim.SetBool ("Ground", false);
            rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0,jumpForce));

            if (!doubleJump && !grounded)
                doubleJump = true;
        }
    }

    void Flip(){
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;

    }
}
```

**aktifChar .cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class aktifChar : AnimCharacter {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.PageUp)) {
                 animation.Play("Running", PlayMode.StopAll);
        }
         }
}
```

*there is a image of the Animator :*
[image]

*the error is saying :* 
MissingComponentException: There is no 'Animation' attached to the "CharacterLamp" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Animation to the game object "CharacterLamp". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
aktifChar.Update () (at Assets/Script/aktifChar.cs:14)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging your code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your script `aktifChar` is attached to an object that doesn't have an Animation component. That's why you're getting a `MissingComponentException` when you try to run this line: `animation.Play("Running", PlayMode.StopAll);`

You probably need to add a Animation to the game object "CharacterLamp". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.

You can check to see if the component exists with:

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.PageUp)) {
        if(this.gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>() != null) {
            animation.Play("Running", PlayMode.StopAll);
        }
    }
}
```